# ASP DropDown item attribute

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am trying to set a background image for certain items of a dropdownlist
But that exactly doesnt work.

Now, this works

```
ddl.Items[0]?.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "red");
ddl.Items[0]?.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "blue");
```

The background is red, text is blue for the first item, rest is normal

However this,

```
ddl.Items[0]?.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-image", "url('ico.png')");
```

does not.

I have also tried this (below) for both cases. Same result

```
ddl.Items[0]?.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image:url('ico.png');");
```

When I set the background-image property in the aspx itself

```
<asp:DropDownList Style="background-image: url('ico.png')" id=../>
```

It's there under the control, but not when the list extends to select an item..

I have read around the internet that you can't even set the simple color, but it worked for me, so if they added the feature later, perhaps this particular attribute was not added for some reason.

Or if you think of another way of adding an icon to certain ddl items, feel free to link/suggest.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
            DropDownList1.DataSource = objdt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Country";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            //Now add class to each and every item in dropdown
            //Now, add a "SysCode" attribute to each item in the dropdown list
            string imageURL = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                switch (DropDownList1.Items[i].Text)
                {
                    case "India": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-India.png";
                        break;
                    case "Kuwait": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-Kuwait.png";
                        break;
                    case "Egypt": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-Egypt.png";
                        break;
                    case "Bangladesh": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-Bangladesh.png";
                        break;
                    case "Afghanistan": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-Afghanistan.png";
                        break;
                }
                ListItem item = DropDownList1.Items[i];
                item.Attributes["style"] = "background: url(" + imageURL + ");background-repeat:no-repeat;";
            }
        }
    }
```